# Smooth shading using Three.js

Tags: three.js

I need anyone to help me about my work

Work here :

ivanvujnovic.com/Avatar_final/index.html

I would have a better rendering, like smooth shading or something else.

How can i do that?

Thank's

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want, but I think your problem is with the model

Answer (score 0):

You already have smooth shading happening there. I believe you might be looking for 'pixel shading' or 'pixel lighting'.

This might be useful:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/lighting.php

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the normals are messed up in your model, or there is a glitch translating them with Three.js making for a bumpy look by messing up the lighting.

You could try to re-export your model and check any normal-related export options if the problem could be solved with using different configuration.

Or you could let Three.js try to recalculate new normals for your geometry, ignoring the ones existing in the model:

```
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Comment: Nope, the normals look ok for what the model is (scanned, triangulater pointcloud it seems). The funky pattern is the result of vertex lighting interpolation. To get smoother results, one would have to first normalize the vertex normal in the pixel shader (this reconstructs the smooth surface at every pixel) and then do the NdotL term for each pixel. I don't know off the to of my head, but there should be a parameter within three.js materials to switch to this.